# Tool to assist scheduling a meeting across multiple time zones

Tags: windows, software-rec, time-zone, meetings

I am looking for a tool that would make it easier to schedule/plan a meeting with participants in different time zones. I am not necessarily looking for a tool that sends out the invitations etc. but I am looking for a tool which would display all the selected timezones next to each other so that I can see the different local time at a glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a useful website here which shows the local time next to each other:
http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meeting.html

Example:
http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingtime.html?day=23&month=2&year=2010&p1=47&p2=37&p3=179&p4=-1

Answer (score 1):

A bit old, but perhaps a round up of more recent ones could be helpful:

http://everytimezone.com/ - Doesn't show every timezone but a good bunch of them at the same time
+ Pretty interface
+ Easy to see how times "flow" over days and locations
- Can't set own location
- Not the most intuitive

http://www.mymeetingtime.com - Time zones in graphical interface
+ Easy to find times with graphical interface, just dragging bubbles
+ Can add as many locations as you want
- Not so many features

http://worldtimebuddy.com - Offers lots of features
+ Many features (send to calendar, integrate with Google, widgets etc.)
+ Clean and nice interface
+ Good search box
- Too much information
- Maximum 4 locations in free version